# "Error in retrofit api call" completes the observable instead of letting the other observable emit items

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I have two observable, one gets list from `SharedPreferences` and the other one gets it from api with retrofit(Ver 1.9.0). I use `mergeDelayError` to let both observables emit their items even after any error.

```
    Observable.mergeDelayError(Observable.just(instance.getListFromSharedPrefs()), instance.getListFromApi())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Item>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("ItemList", "Error: " + e.toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Item> Items) {
                    Log.d("ItemList", "ItemsFetched:" + Items.toString());
                    if (mAdapter != null) {
                        mAdapter.setItems(Items);
                    }
                }
            });
```

But when there is an error with retrofit api call(i.e. No internet connection), the whole process is completed after `onError` and it can not get the list from `SharedPreferences`.

This is the log when app first starts:

```
12-30 15:49:23.044 12197-12197/com.me.android D/itemList: SharedPrefsandroid.app.SharedPreferencesImpl@9b59793
12-30 15:49:23.189 12197-12197/com.me.android D/itemList: SharedPrefsandroid.app.SharedPreferencesImpl@9b59793
12-30 15:49:23.409 12197-12197/com.me.android D/itemList: Error: retrofit.RetrofitError
```

But when i close the app and reopen it everything works fine:

```
12-30 15:51:27.396 12197-12197/com.me.android D/itemList: SharedPrefsandroid.app.SharedPreferencesImpl@9b59793
12-30 15:51:27.426 12197-12197/com.me.android D/itemList: itemsFetched:[com.me.android.model.entity.item.item@676ffe9]
12-30 15:51:27.438 12197-12197/com.me.android D/itemList: SharedPrefsandroid.app.SharedPreferencesImpl@9b59793
12-30 15:51:27.618 12197-12197/com.me.android D/itemList: SharedPrefsandroid.app.SharedPreferencesImpl@9b59793
12-30 15:51:27.700 12197-12197/com.me.android D/itemList: SharedPrefsandroid.app.SharedPreferencesImpl@9b59793
12-30 15:51:27.772 12197-12197/com.me.android D/itemList: Error: retrofit.RetrofitError
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely the `observeOn` which let's onError cut ahead of any value, no matter of the `mergeDelayError` delaying the error after the value.

There is a PR waiting for approval that lets `observeOn` also delay errors, but for now, you can apply `materialize` before `observeOn` and `dematerialize` just after it.

**Edit** Example:

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(
    Observable.just(
        instance.getListFromSharedPrefs()), instance.getListFromApi())
    .materialize()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .dematerialize()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

`mergeDelayError` does not remove the error, it just delays it unit the other observables finish emitting items.

You might wanna try using `onErrorReturn` eg:

```
instance.getListFromSharedPrefs().mergeWith(instance.getListFromApi().onErrorReturn(Observable.empty())
```

to ignore a network in the API call.

Comment: But i want to handle these errors too, not ignoring them.

Comment: @MortezaRastgoo in case of an error in the Retrofit API call what do you want to happen?

Comment: The onComplete method is called after onError, So nothing is emitted from `getListFromSharedPrefs` even if there is something there